# How to automatically change the position of TextViews depending on the size of the image?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, layout

My app allows uploading images of different sizes.  On top of the ImageView, I have 2 TextViews that act as the top and bottom captions of the image. What happens at the moment is that regardless of the images' heights, the top and the bottom textviews are never aligned with their respective position on the image.

What I want is for my `top_text_view` and `bottom_text_view` to always be at the top and bottom ends of the image regardless of the images' heights or widths.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TopImageFragment">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/click"
        android:tag="img1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/meme_image_view"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/meme_image_view"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got it mostly right.

If you remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/meme_image_view"`

from `bottom_text_view` it should work as expected.

This is overriding `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/meme_image_view"` which is what is needed

Comment: How about `android:layout_alignTop="@id/meme_image_view"` in the 1st TextView?

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you please give me an upvote?